# Creating n columns to a dataframe

Tags: r

I'm trying to create multiple columns with a for loop to simulate different kinds of scenarios.

The code I'm thinking of is like

```
X=10    #number of iterations
P=2/14  #Probability of success
n=14    #Nummber of iterations

for (i in 1:X){

P=(qbinom(runif(1), n, P))/n # Random Binomial Probability

Results["i"]=P #I don't know how to do this bit

}
```

the `Results["i"]=P` bit is the part I don't know how to do,
for each iteration I need `X` columns showing in each one the result of the random experiment

Thanks

Comment: What is `ndb` ?
 `replicate(X, qbinom(runif(1), size=n, prob=P))`

Comment: or simply `Results <- qbinom(runif(X), size=n, prob=P)`

Answer (score 1):

here is the help:

declear:

```
results <- NULL
```

and inside the for loop:

```
results <- cbind(results,P) #keep in mind length of P should be same.
```

Comment: Ty! it works. But how may i give a diferent name for each column? like P1, P2, P3....

Comment: @CrisGuN You can use `names(results) <- paste0("P", 1:X)`